# Меш растягивается при повороте кости

Tags: blender

Пример растяжения меша:

[image: скрин1]

Пример растяжения меша крупным планом:

[image: скрин2]

`Auto weight` немного сгладил ситуацию, но все равно меш рвется, вот пример:

[image: скрин3]

Этот же пример, но только крупным планом:

[image: скрин4]

Файл проекта https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yy7c5nb9aq8cr5dqswgf7/HAZMAT-SUIT-NBC.blend?rlkey=u24o6jlpstimif0dycm7h5099&dl=0

Comment: А стартовая поза какая, "А"? Если так, то тут ничего особо не сделать, с таким "мешком".

Comment: Да, стартовая поза A

Comment: Вы забыли задать вопрос. Также уточните, меш, скелет и риг вы сами делали? Можете добавить костей для подмышек и заригать их.

Comment: Ок, попробую этот способ

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать всё. Для этого нужно просто понаблюдать за реальной одеждой. Что происходит, когда человек поднимает руки вверх? Происходят две вещи:

- одежда подтягивается кверху (этого не происходит на картинках);
- рукава подтягиваются к шее (этого тоже нет на картинках).

За счёт этого одежда не растягивается и не рвётся. Так же есть решения в виде специального кроя одежды, например, реглан.

**P. S.**

Смотрю на нижнее чёрное пятно. Его положение относительно тазобедренных суставов не меняется. У него что, одежда гвоздями прибита к телу, или что-то мешает? Когда руки поднимаются, то пройма под мышками тоже поднимается, а не растягивается ткань.

Comment: Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю. Вы же как-то сделали, что костюм растягивается в одном месте, а не по всей длинне. Почему он растягивается только под мышкой? Если вы ответите на этот вопрос, то поймёте, что вам нужно сделать, чтобы это изменить. Хочу добавить как вариант помимо решения этого вопроса, что можно сделать пройму рукава поближе к суставу, тогда растягиваться будет нечему. Выглядеть, наверно, будет не очень.

Comment: @Kromster Спасибо за правки! Но "под мышками" пишется раздельно при употреблении в качестве наречия.

Comment: Не знал, спасибо!